# Unhandled promise rejection Error: a is a void element tag and must neither have `children` nor use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`

Tags: reactjs, internet-explorer-11

I get this errormessage in IE11 in a reactjs app. It seems that there is a problem with placing something into an a-Tag, what is quite normal and should work.

Changing the a-tag to a div-tag lets the error disappear, but it is not a solution. This is reactjs with antd.

```
return (
<>
  <Breadcrumb>
    <Breadcrumb.Item><a href={startPointURI}>{t('breadcrumb-overview')}</a></Breadcrumb.Item>
    <Breadcrumb.Item>
      <Link to="/">
        {t('breadcrumb-jobfinder')}
      </Link>
    </Breadcrumb.Item>
  </Breadcrumb>
</>
);
```

Comment: Show us the code.

Comment: Please provide a **minimal, reproducible sample** according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can have a test and see how to help. With only the above few words, we can't locate the issue. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: are you getting this error in other browsers as well?

Comment: no, only in ie11

Comment: What are `Breadcrumb` and `{t('breadcrumb-overview')}` in your code? Your code is not enough to reproduce. You could try to make a reproducibe sample using online code editor like [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/). Besides, you could also try to add a `<div>` as the parent element of `<a>` to see if it works.

Comment: A div would work

Comment: Has anybody ever heard of the error message "a is a void element tag"? I don't think it is a void element tag.

Comment: Do you mean add `<div>` as the parent element around `<a>` can work? If so I can put that into an answer. Besides, I also think `<a>` isn't a void element. The error is so strange. So I think only a full, reproducible sample can help to locate the issue. Feel free to remove all the sensitive information inside your example project.

Comment: I fixed it with a downgrade of "core-js" to version 3.4.4

Comment: You can put your solution as an answer and mark it as an accepted answer. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.